# Conditional Statement in a map function with es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, map-function

I nee to use the conditional statement in a map function

I am duplicating each single value of a `path d` in a `SVG` but i do not want this happening for the objects `M` and `L` of the array

Here is an example of the array as string.

```
M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999 L 175 0
```

This is an example to my case without the conditional statement

```
let neWd = array.map(x => { return x * 2; }).reverse().join(' ')
```

how can i write down this in **e6** ? I don not want the multiplication happening for the elements `L` and `M` ( something like `if x ? 'M' : 'L' return` )

Comment: You'd do it the same way you'd write a conditional statement in any other context. There's nothing special about code in a `.map()` callback.

Comment: can you please add an example of your `array`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure why your using the `reverse` function also, reversing the svg path is slightly more complicated.

This code snippet doubles all the numbers, but leaves `M` and `L` intact.

In effect scaling up the svg path by 200%

```js
var array = "M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999 L 175 0".split(" ");

let neWd = array.map(x => {
 if (x === 'M' || x === 'L'){
  return x;
 }else{
  return x * 2;
 }
}).join(' ')

console.log(neWd);
```

Comment: yes it was not necessary add the reverse.join for the question, this was because i need those values applied in the dom so in order to map i converted in an array and then in a string again

Comment: `join` makes sense like you say to get from array back to a string. just wanted to stress `reverse` on the svg path will not reverse the path.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just do it:

```
let neWd = array.map(x => {
    if (x == "M" || x == "L")
        return x; // unchanged
    else
        return String(parseInt(x, 10) * 2);
}).reverse().join(' ')
```

Comment: You still haven't shown your case (an example of `array`) so I cannot specialise the answer more. But you can [edit] it yourself if you want

Comment: this is the array converted in a string M 175 0  L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001  L 326.55444566227675 262.5  L 175 350  L 23.445554337723223 262.5  L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999 L 175 0

Comment: That's a string, not an array. Have you parsed it into some data structure such as `[{op:"M", vals:[175,0]}, {op:"L", vals:[326.55444566227675, 87.5]}, …]`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Es6 syntax

```
let neWd = array.map((x) => (x == "M" || x == "L") ?
x : String(parseInt(x, 10) * 2)).reverse().join(' ')
```