# checks the data type of array with loop and conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

i want to check the array for the same datatypes. i found other solutions here but i want to do it with for loop and if conditonals.
Can someone please explain, why my code is not working:

thank you very much!

```js
function sameDataType(array){
    const helper = []
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        let dataType0 = typeof(array[i])
        let dataType1 = typeof(array[i+1])
        if(dataType0 === dataType1){
            helper.push(1)
        } else {
            helper.push("not")
            }    
    }    
    for(let j = 0; j < helper.length; j++){
        if(helper[j] === helper[j+1]){
            return "same"
        } else {
            return "different"
        }
    }
}
console.log(sameDataType([1, 1, "string"]))
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? Same when all are same and different when even one of them is different?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Can you check out this link which uses the Array map method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554604/conditional-statement-in-a-map-function-with-es6

Answer (score 0):

Please use Array.map and Array.filter function.

First you get array of types.

And then filter it with removing the duplicated values.

Then check the length.

Like this.

```js
function sameDataType1(array){
    return array.map(val => typeof val).filter((val, index, self) => self.indexOf(val) === index).length === 1 ? "same" : "different";
}
console.log(sameDataType1([1, 1, "string"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Will try to improve upon your code only.

Firstly check if the array even has enough elements. If only one element, simply return `same`.
Then make sure you run your loop till the correct indices. Notice you have `i+1` & `j+1` in your code. You do `arr[arr.length+1]`, you are getting `undefined`.

Also check for the condition when you have only two elements.

```js
function sameDataType(array){
if(array.length > 1 ) {
    const helper = []
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        let dataType0 = typeof(array[i])
        let dataType1 = typeof(array[i+1])
        if(dataType0 === dataType1){
            helper.push(1)
        } else {
            helper.push("not")
            }    
    }    
 
    if(helper.length  === 1 ){
    if(helper[0] === 1) return "same";
    return "different";
    
    }
    for(let j = 0; j < helper.length-1; j++){
        if(helper[j] === 1 && helper[j] === helper[j+1]){
            return "same"
        } else {
            return "different"
        }
    }
}
return "same";
}
console.log(sameDataType([1, 1 , "string"]))
console.log(sameDataType([1, "string:" ]))
console.log(sameDataType(["string", "string" , "string"]))
```

Comment: thank you very much!
but why did you use < array.length -1  ?
I think it should be <= array.length -1

Comment: If `i = array.length - 1`, `i+1 =  array.length`. So for an array of length 3 you cannot do array[3] right, that is `undefined`. And comparing your element with undefined is false only right. Why do it